# Why is my user-defined function's 'int' object not callable?

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, callable

I created a user-defined function and keep getting the error message "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" when I try to print

```
import math
def rangeeee(x, ang, vo, yo):
    fl=(yo+x*math.tan(math.radians(ang))-(1/(2*vo*vo))*((9.8*x*x)/(math.cos**2(math.radians(ang)))))
    return fl

print(rangeeee(1,2,3,4))
```

Comment: `math.cos**2(math.radians(ang))` is where the problem is. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Presumably you meant to call `math.cos()` of something, but you forgot the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

### `math.cos()` is improperly used:

- `math.cos(math.radians(ang))**2` instead of `(math.cos**2(math.radians(ang)))`

  - note the placement of `math.radians(ang)` inside the `()` of [`math.cos()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions)
  - [image]
  - [image]
  - [image]

```py
def range_e(x: float, ang: float, vo: float, yo: float) -> float:
    return (yo + 
            x * math.tan(math.radians(ang)) - 
            (1 / (2 * vo**2)) * 
            ((9.8 * x**2) / math.cos(math.radians(ang))**2))

print(range_e(1,2,3,4))

>>> 3.489812396747827
```

- The function has been updated with [Type annotations](https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/#annotations) (e.g. `range_e(x: float, ang: float, vo: float, yo: float) -> float:`)
- The equation has been separated into different lines for readability
- The function has been renamed to `range_e`, as it's easier than `rangeeee`, and `range` would overwrite a [built-in python function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)
- The equation can be `returned` without assigning it to `f1`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do `math.cos((math.radians(ang)*2))`